# ASP.NET Core WebAPI Cookie + JWT Authentication

Tags: c#, authentication, cookies, asp.net-core, jwt

we have a SPA (Angular) with API backend (ASP.NET Core WebAPI):

SPA is listens on `app.mydomain.com`, API on `app.mydomain.com/API`

We use JWT for Authentication with built-in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer`; I have a controller `app.mydomain.com/API/auth/jwt/login` which creates tokens. SPA saves them into local storage. All works perfect. After a security audit, we have been told to switch local storage for cookies.

The problem is, that API on `app.mydomain.com/API` is used by SPA but also by a mobile app and several customers server-2-server solutions.

So, we have to keep JWT as is, but add Cookies. I found several articles which combines Cookies and JWT on different controllers, but I need them work side-by-side on each controller.

If client sends cookies, authenticate via cookies. If client sends JWT bearer, authenticate via JWT.

Is this achievable via built-in ASP.NET authentication or DIY middleware?

Thanks!

Comment: Using cookies for your MVC controllers is fine, but I would advice against using cookies for WebAPI because your api becomes vulnerable to [Cross Site Request Forgery / XSRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) and securing that is a bigger pain in the butt (Anti Request forgery on WebAPI is a bigger pain in the ass than in MVC Apps).

Comment: Using local storage is perfectly fine as long as you don't allow people to run / inject java script code in your application (i.e. if your app doesn't allow user input, then its quite easier to secure it when you don't have arbitrary user input which is displayed/rendered again (such as a bulletin board or chat application)

Comment: Thank you sir! Well, we have 0 MVC controllers, only WebAPI. Unfortunately, app allows a lot of user input, even HTML (WYSIWYG) for custom report / template modifications.

Comment: Well may still be better than cookie and webapi. It could make attackers perform actions with the logged in users permissions if he can lure him to any other side or a hidden form where you have even less control. On top of that, Antiforgery request requires a state (cookie and the correct token on the server to compare with later) , which violates REST-services "stateless" nature. Also issuing new AntiRequest forgery tokens isn't intuitive in SPAs, you'd need to request the server every single time before you send a request to obtain a new token valid for the next request

Comment: Your best bet imho is, using opaque (or reference token in IdentityServer 4 terms) token. Its still required to send the token on every request, but you can enable token validation, so you can rather quickly revoke tokens in case it gets compromised and use. Also you could put the users IP into the token when issued and if the IP changes it gets invalidated. More annoying for the user, but it prevents an attacker from using either the access or refresh tokens himself (unless again, the user can inject javascript code into the application).

Comment: But both approaches (Cookie and JWT) are suspectible to attacks when code is injected. Http Cookie doesnt allow the attacker to **steal** the cookie, but he can still perform actions on behalf of the logged in user. Same for JWT cookies stored in local storage with the exception that they can also steal the tokens themselves, but this can be prevented by putting IP as a claim into the token and validating it on the server or at least made harder (IP can be spoofed, but the attacker can't get any response). Complex topic

Comment: I understand your point of view, in fact, I have no experience with anti request forgery technique in WebAPI so I cannot realy compare the effort. But, according to this article, and many others - https://stormpath.com/blog/where-to-store-your-jwts-cookies-vs-html5-web-storage - recommended storage is cookies. However, I completely agree with RESTful principle violation. Any way, I am trying to get more deep into ASP.NET Authentication, how they can be combined, because we have incoming story in backlog - Google / Facebook Authentication..

Comment: _ Since only JavaScript that runs on your domain can read the cookie, your server can be assured that the XHR came from JavaScript running on your domain._ From the linked article, is the exact same vulnerability as when storing the jwt in local storage.Once you have javascript code injected into your web application,it can either perform actions on behalf of the user or steal the token, both leading to unwanted access. Only difference is,the token can't be stolen.And XSRF token requires state. Could also be a bit bias, since the article is from the developers of the sdk mentioned in the post

Comment: Also interesting read https://auth0.com/blog/cookies-vs-tokens-definitive-guide/ (from an commercial openauth/openid provider, 0auth)

Comment: Thanks for your effort. We will re-open the security audit recommendations and will have a brainstorming @work.

Comment: Take a look at this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46938248/asp-net-core-2-0-combining-cookies-and-bearer-authorization-for-the-same-endpoin

Answer (score 14):

Okay, I have been trying achieving this for a while and i solved same issue of using jwt Authentication Tokens and Cookie Authentication with the following code.

API Service Provider **UserController.cs**

> This Provide Different Services to the User with Both (Cookie and JWT Bearer)Authentication Schemes

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)] 
[Route("[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class UsersController : ControllerBase
{ 
    private readonly IUserServices_Api _services;
    public UsersController(IUserServices_Api services)
    {
        this._services = services;
    }
     
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<User> Getall()
    {
        return _services.GetAll();
    }
}
```

My **Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
          
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
         
        services.AddAuthentication(options => {
            options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
            .AddCookie(options =>
            {
                options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
                options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Home/Error";
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.SaveToken = true;
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters()
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidAudience = " you site link blah blah",
                    ValidIssuer = "You Site link Blah  blah",
                    IssuerSigningKey = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SymmetricSecurityKey(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sysController.GetSecurityKey()))
                    ,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
                };
            });

    }
```

And further if you want custom Authentication for a specific Controller
then you have to specify the Authentitcation Type for the Authorization
like:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View();    // This can only be Access when Cookie Authentication is Authorized.
}

[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View();    // And this one will be Access when JWT Bearer is Valid
}
```

Comment: Have you noticed that you have duplicate claims after implementing like this? I also have Jwt & Cookie setup for webapi and MVC and I have two sets of same claims. It's kind of annoying. I have raided a question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68558515/asp-net-core-identity-avoiding-duplicate-claims-when-using-cookies-and-jwt-authe and no positive response.

Comment: Yes but that is just a sample example, we have to change the Method Names , in this case `Index()`.

Answer (score 7):

I've been having the same issue and i just found what it seems to be the solution in another question here in stackoverflow.

Please take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46942760).

I'll try that solution myself and update this answer with the results.

Edit: It seems it's not possible to achieve double authentication types in a same method but the solution provided in the link i mentioned says:

> It's not possible to authorize a method with two Schemes Or-Like, but you can use two public methods, to call a private method
>
> ```
> //private method
> private IActionResult GetThingPrivate()
> {
>    //your Code here
> }
> //Jwt-Method
> [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = $"{JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme}")]
> [HttpGet("bearer")]
> public IActionResult GetByBearer()
> {
>    return GetThingsPrivate();
> }
>  //Cookie-Method
> [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = $"{CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme}")]
> [HttpGet("cookie")]
> public IActionResult GetByCookie()
> {
>    return GetThingsPrivate();
> }
> ```

Anyway you should take a look at the link, it sure helped me.
Credit goes to Nikolaus for the answer.

Answer (score 5):

I have not been able to find much information on a good way to do this - having to duplicate the API is a pain just to support 2 authorization schemes.

I have been looking into the idea of using a reverse proxy and it looks to me like a good solution for this.

1. User signs into Website (use cookie httpOnly for session)
2. Website uses Anti-Forgery token
3. SPA sends request to website server and includes anti-forgery token in header: https://app.mydomain.com/api/secureResource
4. Website server verifies anti-forgery token (CSRF)
5. Website server determines request is for API and should send it to the reverse proxy
6. Website server gets users access token for API
7. Reverse proxy forwards request to API: https://api.mydomain.com/api/secureResource

**Note that the anti-forgery token (#2,#4) is critical or else you could expose your API to CSRF attacks.**

---

**Example (.NET Core 2.1 MVC with IdentityServer4):**

To get a working example of this I started with the IdentityServer4 quick start [Switching to Hybrid Flow and adding API Access back](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/quickstarts/5_hybrid_and_api_access.html).  This sets up the scenario I was after where a MVC application uses cookies and can request an access_token from the identity server to make calls the API.

I used [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Proxy](https://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.aspnetcore.proxy) for the reverse proxy and modified the quick start.

MVC Startup.ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddAntiforgery();
services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

MVC Startup.Configure:

```
app.MapWhen(IsApiRequest, builder =>
{
    builder.UseAntiforgeryTokens();

    var messageHandler = new BearerTokenRequestHandler(builder.ApplicationServices);
    var proxyOptions = new ProxyOptions
    {
        Scheme = "https",
        Host = "api.mydomain.com",
        Port = "443",
        BackChannelMessageHandler = messageHandler
    };
    builder.RunProxy(proxyOptions);
});

private static bool IsApiRequest(HttpContext httpContext)
{
    return httpContext.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith(@"/api/", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
}
```

[ValidateAntiForgeryToken](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2017/06/11/global-antiforgery-token-validation-in-asp-net-core) (Marius Schulz):

```
public class ValidateAntiForgeryTokenMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate next;
    private readonly IAntiforgery antiforgery;

    public ValidateAntiForgeryTokenMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, IAntiforgery antiforgery)
    {
        this.next = next;
        this.antiforgery = antiforgery;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        await antiforgery.ValidateRequestAsync(context);
        await next(context);
    }
}

public static class ApplicationBuilderExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseAntiforgeryTokens(this IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        return app.UseMiddleware<ValidateAntiForgeryTokenMiddleware>();
    }
}
```

BearerTokenRequestHandler:

```
public class BearerTokenRequestHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider serviceProvider;

    public BearerTokenRequestHandler(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, HttpMessageHandler innerHandler = null)
    {
        this.serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        InnerHandler = innerHandler ?? new HttpClientHandler();
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var httpContextAccessor = serviceProvider.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
        var accessToken = await httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
        request.Headers.Authorization =new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
        var result = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        return result;
    }
}
```

_Layout.cshtml:

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

Then using your SPA framework you can make a request.  To verify I just did a simple AJAX request:

```
<a onclick="sendSecureAjaxRequest()">Do Secure AJAX Request</a>
<div id="ajax-content"></div>

<script language="javascript">
function sendSecureAjaxRequest(path) {
    var myRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    myRequest.open('GET', '/api/secureResource');
    myRequest.setRequestHeader("RequestVerificationToken",
        document.getElementsByName('__RequestVerificationToken')[0].value);
    myRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (myRequest.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            if (myRequest.status === 200) {
                document.getElementById('ajax-content').innerHTML = myRequest.responseText;
            } else {
                alert('There was an error processing the AJAX request: ' + myRequest.status);
            }
        }  
    };
    myRequest.send();
};
</script>
```

This was a proof of concept test so your mileage may very and I'm pretty new to .NET Core and middleware configuration so it could probably look prettier.  I did limited testing with this and only did a GET request to the API and did not use SSL (https).

As expected, if the anti-forgery token is removed from the AJAX request it fails.  If the user is has not logged in (authenticated) the request fails.

As always, each project is unique so always verify your security requirements are met. Please take a look at any comments left on this answer for any potential security concerns someone might raise.

*On another note, I think once subresource integrity (SRI) and content security policy (CSP) is available on all commonly used browsers (i.e. older browsers are phased out) local storage should be re-evaluated to store API tokens which will lesson the complexity of token storage.*  SRI and CSP should be used now to help reduce the attack surface for supporting browsers.

Answer (score 5):

with this code you can use cookie and header in the same time.
if cookie is null then check the header automatically.

add this code in AddJwtBearer options.

```
options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
{
    OnMessageReceived = context =>
    {
        context.Token = context.Request.Cookies["Authorization"];
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
};
```

full usage is:

```
        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
            {
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.SaveToken = false;
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidAudience = Configuration["JwtToken:Audience"],
                    ValidIssuer = Configuration["JwtToken:Issuer"],
                    IssuerSigningKey =
                        new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["JwtToken:Key"]))
                };
                options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                {
                    OnMessageReceived = context =>
                    {
                        context.Token = context.Request.Cookies["Authorization"];
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                };
            });
```

Header => Authorization: Bearer Your-Token

or

Cookie => Authorization=Your-Token
//dont add Bearer in Cookie

Comment: This was the cleanest way to solve the problem for me.  You can add additional filtering on the `Request` object to filter when to use this fallback.  You could check for the presence of the `Authentication` header to make the bearer token take precedence or check the path to enable this for specific endpoints.

Answer (score 4):

I think the easiest solution is one proposed by [David Kirkland](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55627054/4553518):

Create combined authorization policy (in `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)`):

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    var defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(
        CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
        JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder =
        defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
    options.DefaultPolicy = defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder.Build();
});
```

And add middleware that will redirect to login in case of 401 (in `Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)`):

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    await next();
    var bearerAuth = context.Request.Headers["Authorization"]
        .FirstOrDefault()?.StartsWith("Bearer ") ?? false;
    if (context.Response.StatusCode == 401
        && !context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
        && !bearerAuth)
    {
        await context.ChallengeAsync("oidc");
    }
});
```

Comment: how the middleware may be modified to also support XMLHttpRequest() ?
In case of ajax calls using XMLHttpRequest, when the line
await context.ChallangeAsync() is hit, it returns status = 200 and login html page?

Answer (score 3):

while looking for combined firebase authorization with net core web api (cookie for web site and authorization header for mobile app ) end with the following solution.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
               .AddJwtBearer(options =>
               {
                   options.Authority = "https://securetoken.google.com/xxxxx";
                   options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                   {
                       ValidateIssuer = true,
                       ValidIssuer = options.Authority,
                       ValidateAudience = true,
                       ValidAudience = "xxxxx",
                       ValidateLifetime = true
                   };
                   options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                   {
                       OnMessageReceived = context =>
                       {
                           if (context.Request.Cookies.ContainsKey(GlobalConst.JwtBearer))
                           {
                               context.Token = context.Request.Cookies[GlobalConst.JwtBearer];
                           }
                           else if (context.Request.Headers.ContainsKey("Authorization"))
                                {
                                    var authhdr = context.Request.Headers["Authorization"].FirstOrDefault(k=>k.StartsWith(GlobalConst.JwtBearer));
                                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(authhdr))
                                    {
                                        var keyval = authhdr.Split(" ");
                                        if (keyval != null && keyval.Length > 1) context.Token = keyval[1];
                                    }
                                }
                           return Task.CompletedTask;
                       }
                   };
               });
```

where

```
 public static readonly string JwtBearer = "Bearer";
```

seems working fine.
checked it from mobile & postman (for cookie )

Answer (score 2):

I found [this](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2022/Mar/29/Combining-Bearer-Token-and-Cookie-Auth-in-ASPNET) nice article by Rick Strahl. It is the best solution that I found so far and I used it in .NET 5

Here is the key code in order to combining JWT token and cookie authentication in .NET applications:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options => 
{
    options.DefaultScheme = "JWT_OR_COOKIE";
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "JWT_OR_COOKIE";
})
.AddCookie( options =>
{
    options.LoginPath = "/login";
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
})
.AddJwtBearer( options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidIssuer = config.JwtToken.Issuer,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidAudience = config.JwtToken.Audience,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(config.JwtToken.SigningKey))
    };
})
.AddPolicyScheme("JWT_OR_COOKIE", "JWT_OR_COOKIE", options =>
{
    options.ForwardDefaultSelector = context =>
    {
        string authorization = context.Request.Headers[HeaderNames.Authorization];
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(authorization) && authorization.StartsWith("Bearer "))
            return JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            
        return CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    };
});
```

Answer (score -1):

**ASP.NET Core 2.0 Web API**

Please follow this post for implementing **JWT Token** based authentication

**https://fullstackmark.com/post/13/jwt-authentication-with-aspnet-core-2-web-api-angular-5-net-core-identity-and-facebook-login**

If you are using visual studio make sure apply the Bearer type athentication type with the filter

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
```

for controller or actions.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: This will allow to call method only with JWT, not with cookies.

Comment: @user369450 no issues. Since i can't paste every thing here.. We published it separately    

https://fullstackmark.com/post/13/jwt-authentication-with-aspnet-core-2-web-api-angular-5-net-core-identity-and-facebook-login