# asp.net core identity avoiding duplicate claims when using cookies and jwt authentication schemes

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

In my application, there is a part where cookie authentication takes place and some apis that relies on jwt. So I am using two schemes (Cookie & JWT). Asp.net Identity handles the cookie authentication and a custom api handles jwt. Both of these methods call a common method to create the claims.

So what happense is now cookie has X no. of claims and the JWT token also have the same number of claims.

But at any given point in time when I check the Principal.Identity.Claims, it has duplicates (from Cookies & JWT).

I am sure this happense by some middleware in which it collects claims from cookie & jwt and then prepare the principal for the request.

Is there a way to avoid this duplication? May be write my own middleware? If so what should I override in the pipeline?

Comment: Could you please tell us more details about your application? If one user wants to access the api and identity protected resources, do they need login in both identity and JWT or not?

Comment: application primarily uses MVC. So, user authentication happens without using a web api (using AspNet core Identit). So once the user is authenticated, I am creating a token as well using the same claims (now we have a cookie + token) that goes to the client. In client side Vuejs accepts the JWT token and uses it whenever it needs to call webapis in certain places in the application. For other areas where post backs are happening it uses the claims in the cookie. it all works fine except that duplication of claims.

Comment: Try making separate controllers, and also use the `services.AddScoped<IUserServices_Api, SQLUserRepository>();`   for the services. give it a try...
Can you please show atleast the startup code?