ASP.NET Core 6 Web API : JWT never refreshes in the API
The primary question is this: why can I not send the API a single string in the requests without trying to access the HttpClient or HttpRequestMessage, or have the Auth Header actually work correctly?
I am trying to build a site and an API, both of which talk to each other using a JWT. That works. Authentication and authorization are perfect.
Now, trying to pull the user ID from the API is a wee bit challenging.  I've tried the common routes of
UserId = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?
                            .User?
                            .FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name)?
                            .Value ?? string.Empty;

and a myriad of other solutions.
If I add cookies from the site like...middleware -->
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
{
    try
    {               
        httpContext.Request.Headers.SetCookie = new StringValues("this never works");
    }
    catch()
    { }
}

The cookie never makes it to the API. If I add headers to the API, they never make it unless I setup default headers (which will be painful).
I've tried to use AuthenticationHeaderValue with
HttpRequestMessage? httpRequestMessage = httpContext.Items["MS_HttpRequestMessage"] as HttpRequestMessage;
var bear = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(scheme: "Bearer", parameter: token);

This also fails httpContext.Items["MS_HttpRequestMessage"] - in that scenario the item doesn't exist.
The Auth Header with the bearer token is the part that is wrong.  I could fix that or try another approach, which is what I am doing since the Header never has the actual session user and is always stale (the previous user).
Why would I try the above, right? Because the API never "sees" the current user's JWT, it always has the JWT for the previous user. So, in this example, I log into the system with my ID, it recognizes me and everything is copacetic.
However, when user X logs into the system, it still retains my JWT even though I am on a completely separate server and using a completely separate browsing session. How is the API caching this information? How does it cache the JWT?
The website has the JWT on a per user basis, and the website JWT is always perfect:
var parsedSessionJwt = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler()
    .ReadJwtToken(token)
    .Claims
    .ToList();

Pasting this value into jwt.io always works from the site.
Trying to mix and match Identity such that I can use the Microsoft solution of IPrincipal and IIdentity with a JWT doesn't seem practical and has too many hurdles that I've faced. Identity is overly complex and very rigid in my experience.
What I would love to have, ultimately, is a middleware that sends the API a header or cookie, or header cookie, or....that is the actual real JWT for the current user.  That JWT is accurate in the website as user X, Y, and Zed.  I can send an ID, I've built a table that catches all logged in users in the DB and their assigned GUID. I could pass that. An accurate, no-cached value that the API can retrieve.
I am trying to "tell" the API that I have a value, but nothing is being propagated from the Request to the API.
Is it in the setup?
Website services:
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(auth =>
{
    auth.DefaultAuthenticateScheme      = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    auth.DefaultChallengeScheme         = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    auth.DefaultForbidScheme            = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    //auth.RequireAuthenticatedSignIn     = true;
})
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
          ValidateIssuer            = true
        , ValidateAudience          = true
        , ValidateLifetime          = true
        , ValidateIssuerSigningKey  = true
        , ValidIssuer               = jwtOptionsIssuer
        , ValidAudience             = jwtOptionsAudience
        , IssuerSigningKey          = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jwtOptionsKey))
        , ClockSkew                 = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30)  
        , RequireExpirationTime     = true
    };
    // the https address of the website httpS
    options.Authority = "someservername"; // 

    //options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
    //{
    //    OnMessageReceived = context =>
    //    {
    //        context.Token = context.Request.Cookies["jwtCookie"];
    //        return Task.CompletedTask;
    //    }
    //};
});

API services
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(auth =>
       {
           auth.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
           auth.DefaultChallengeScheme    = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
           auth.DefaultForbidScheme       = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
           //auth.RequireAuthenticatedSignIn = true;
       });

And I have an independent project in the solution for the home cooked identity which does this:
public async Task<AuthenticationResponse> AuthenticateAsync(AuthenticationRequest request)
{
    try
    {
        if (!IsUserExisting(request?.uniqueId ?? string.Empty,
                            request?.Domain ?? string.Empty)) 
             throw new Exception($"{ request?.uniqueId}; " + "no user!");

        var user = new User 
                   {
                       Domain   = request?.Domain ?? throw new NullReferenceException("You must provide Domain Name."),
                       EID      = request?.EmployeeID ?? throw new NullReferenceException("You must provide Employee ID."),
                       Password = request?.Password ?? throw new NullReferenceException("You must provide a Password.")
                   };

        var message = string.Empty;

        // You must authenticate with AD
        var authenticated = AuthenticateActiveDirectory(request.uniqueId, request.Password, request.Domain, out message);

        if (!authenticated)
        {
            return new AuthenticationResponse
            {
                ErrorMessage = $"Credentials for '{request.uniqueId} aren't valid'."
            };
        }

        IsAuthenticated = true;
        user.EmployeeName   = GetUserFromForest?.GetUser(user.uniqueId)?.Surname ?? "No User!";
        user.Role           = GetUserFromForest?.GetGroupsAndClaims(user.uniqueId, request.Domain);

        JwtSecurityToken jwtSecurityToken = await GenerateToken(user);

        var identifier = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        AuthenticationResponse response = new AuthenticationResponse
        {
            Id           = identifier,
            Token        = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(jwtSecurityToken),
            UserName     = user.uniqueId,
            Role         = user.Role,
            EmployeeName = user.Surname
        };

        return response;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
}

I am not a 100% sure, but I don't think that I am affected by ambient state. If I decompose the JWT in the controller, it is still the same stale JWT.
Any help that anyone can provide would be very much appreciated; this has cost me three days' time for such a trivial task...

How about append the cookie in your middleware like this.

The web needs to populate the request with the answer for the API, then the response needs to contain it.  You're populating the response in the web?

You are trying to provide a jwt with every request from a web app to an api and some or all of it is coming over as null or empty on the api side?

@RossBush Yes, if I set the cookies in the header, they don't come over.  If I set a header, it doesn't come over.

Did you see this? --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49455943/asp-net-core-webapi-cookie-jwt-authentication

If you have the JWT saved in the database, then optionally, just pass the identifier of that record in the auth header or query string. &authid=GUID. If you know the record in your database is accurate and the jwt in the http request matches what is currently valid, then that is one way to go about it. Just make sure those records have a valid ttl or some type of sliding expiration.

@RossBush I am reviewing the documentation on the previous post that you did and trying to work thought it.  The piece that I am seeing that indicates the JWT is a constant is here: _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", authenticationResponse.Token);  But the lifecycle of this should be handed out with every request, right?  This shouldn't be causing the issue I am seeing.  Otherwise, how would you assign the token you get back from the HTTPResponse in the HTTPMessage?  It's already sent.

@RossBush I feel like adding that &authid=GUID could have some merit if I can get that in the middleware for the query string.  Nothing I put in the header makes it to the API, but the site has it and when I debug it, all the values are populated.

@cyimxtck - Sounds like the lifecycle needs to be per-call.

@RossBush My entire idea when I started was to have a jot in the header after I authenticated the user with the API, send it back to the website and have it returned in the site on every subsequent request.  That doesn't work, which is hard to understand considering the entire point of a jot, seemingly, is to authorize and authenticate.

@RossBush When you say "per call", how would you envision that transpiring?  Everything is fired with button click events and the API handles those in a FIFO model.  What could I do manually, or ensure is happening, in order to implement per call?

Sorry, I was referring to where you said the jwt was stale. That either means some sort of session is being used or the client was not properly sending the next JWT, I bet the latter.

@RossBush I am running out of ideas...I cannot get the API to "see" anything I create in the middleware.  Meaning, I have created headers, querystrings, you name it.  The middleware successfully applies the assignments, but when I view the API itself there's no value for the previously assigned objects.  Do you have any idea what could be happening here?
