# I get 401, When I Combined Bearer Token and Cookie Authentication in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-authorization

I need to combine token and cookies for authorizing requests in wepapi project.
I have added Cookies and Jwt for authenticating requests.
Before changing DefaultPolicy, I can get my claims(/info), But after changing i get 401.

Here is my Program.cs codes:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    }).AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.Authority = "https://localhost:7208/";
        options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateAudience = false;
        options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidTypes = new[] { "at+jwt" };
    });

var multiSchemePolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(
        CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
        JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
    .Build();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(o =>
{
    o.DefaultPolicy = multiSchemePolicy;
});

var app = builder.Build();


app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

And controller codes:

```
namespace Whois.Api.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class AccountController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet("info")]
        [Authorize]
        public IActionResult Info()
        {
            return Ok(User.Claims.Select(m => m.Value));
        }
        [HttpPost("login")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login()
        {
            var user = _userManager.Users.FirstOrDefault();

            await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, new AuthenticationProperties() { });
            return Ok();
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any solution?

Comment: You could set the authentication schema inside the controller, then it could use the JWT authentication to authe the request not the cookie authentication.

More details, you could refer to this codes:

    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is when you signin with signInManager it will add Identity.Application not cookies.

[image]

Solution:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
.AddCookie()
.AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options => { });

var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder("Identity.Application", "Bearer")
.RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(m => m.DefaultPolicy = policy);
```

replace CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme with Identity.Application when building you policy.