# Authorize ASP.NET Core 2.1 controller with several schemes at once

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core-2.1, authorize-attribute, multiple-schema

Lets assume that we are using authentication with "Abc" schema and respective handler and everything is great. We are able to secure controller simply with

`[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Abc", Roles = "admin")]` attribute

But now appeared need to be able to secure controller's endpoints with "Xyz" schema as well (so request should correspond to demands of **both** schemes).
So, I thought that registering new schema and handler are enough to be able to use `[Authorize]` as follows and receive `AND` logic:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Abc", Roles = "admin")]
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Xyz")]
public class UserController : ControllerBase 
{
}
```

But instead valid request to controller results in *"Forbidden"* response status (note that not even in *"Unauthorized"*).

Also I find it interesting, that when we are applying `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Xyz")]` on action method instead of controller - everything works as desired.

P.S: `MvcOptions.AllowCombiningAuthorizeFilters` in `Startup` is already set to `false`.

I am guessing that it still somehow merges authorization logic when both of attributes present at same (controller in this case) level.

Does anyone know what I'm missing?
Probably I think in wrong direction at all and there is a appropriate way to do multi schema authentication
So, please, feel free to provide your ideas.

Answer (score 1):

I think this might have been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45695382/1226915).

When you see complex authorization attributes like in this case, policy-based authorization can help keep things maintainable and simple.

What you would end up with using policies is something like

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("MyPolicy", policy =>
    {
        policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
        policy.RequireRole("Admin");
        policy.AddAuthenticationSchemes("Abc", "Xyz");
    });
});
```

and you'd decorate either your controller or any of its methods with nothing more than

```
[Authorize(Policy = "MyPolicy")]
```

Have a look at the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-2.1) as well to find out how it's done and what it can offer you.