# How to merge multiple authentication schema in one (Custom Authentication)

Tags: authentication, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, ocelot, asp.net-core-authenticationhandler

I have multiple authentication in my .NET Core API using [add multiple Jwt bearer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49694383/use-multiple-jwt-bearer-authentication), assume I have `Schema1`, `Schema2` and `Schema3`.

I'm also using [Ocelot](https://ocelot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) to manage requests. In Ocelot config for each route I could declare one and only one authentication type (schema name). However in some scenarios I need to have multiple authentication support for each route. (I need to authenticate request with either of `Schema1`, `Schema2` or `Schema3`).

But as Ocelot just let me add one schema name, I have to merge these 3 schemas to 1 schema.

So the basic question is: How could I define one authentication schema (`SchemaX`) which authenticate by `Schema1` or `Schema2` or `Schema3`? Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create custom AuthorizeFilter to allow multiple authentication schema like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51925820/5751404)  or  write a custom middleware that check url route from http context and manually calls `AuthenticateAsync()` and creates a `ClaimsPrincipal` containing all the identities you need like :

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
  var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal();

  var result1 = await context.AuthenticateAsync("MyScheme");
  if (result1?.Principal != null)
  {
      principal.AddIdentities(result1.Principal.Identities);
  }

  var result2 = await context.AuthenticateAsync("MyScheme2");
  if (result2?.Principal != null)
  {
      principal.AddIdentities(result2.Principal.Identities);
  }

  context.User = principal;

  await next();
});
```

Of course you can also move the authentication logic from three schemes into one scheme .

Answer (score 0):

It was simple, I answer it here if somebody looking for:

Basically just need to define a [custom AuthenticationHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.authenticationhandler-1):

```cs
public class DynamicAuthenticationOptions : AuthenticationSchemeOptions
{
}
```

```cs
public class DynamicAuthenticationHandler : AuthenticationHandler<DynamicAuthenticationOptions>
{

    public DynamicAuthenticationHandler(
        IOptionsMonitor<DynamicAuthenticationOptions> options,
        ILoggerFactory logger,
        UrlEncoder encoder,
        ISystemClock clock
    )
        : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
    {
    }

    protected override Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        if (!Request.Headers.ContainsKey("Authorization"))
            return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Fail("Unauthorized"));

        string authorizationHeader = Request.Headers["Authorization"];
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(authorizationHeader))
            return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Fail("Unauthorized"));

        if (!authorizationHeader.StartsWith("bearer", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Fail("Unauthorized"));

        var token = authorizationHeader.Substring("bearer".Length).Trim();

        IEnumerable<Claim> claims;

        foreach (var validMergedSchema in validMergedSchemas)
        {
            if (IsTokenValid(token, validMergedSchema, out claims))
            {
                var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, Scheme.Name);
                var principal = new System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal(identity, null);
                var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(principal, Scheme.Name);
                return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket));
            }
        }

        return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Fail("Unauthorized"));

    }

    private bool IsTokenValid(string tokenStr, string schema, out IEnumerable<Claim> claims)
    {
        claims = null;

        switch (schema.ToLower())
        {
            case "schema1":
                return IsTokenValidBySchema1(tokenStr, out claims);

            case "schema2":
                return IsTokenValidBySchema2(tokenStr, out claims);

            case "schema3":
                return IsTokenValidBySchema3(tokenStr, out claims);

            default:
                return false;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the functionality of the IsTokenValidBySchema1, IsTokenValidBySchema2...

How are these functions connected to the already defined authentication schemes?

Also validMergedSchemas are not defined