# How do I combine authentication schemes using AND in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, basic-authentication, .net-5

I have an ASP.NET Core Web API project that requires `X-API-Key` for all controllers.

Additionally, in some controllers I need to identify (authenticate) user. I want to use basic authentication.

How do I combine multiple authentication schemes using a logical AND?

Comment: Check out these questions: [How do I setup multiple auth schemes in ASP.NET Core 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45695382/8065832) and [Use multiple JWT Bearer Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49694383/8065832).

Comment: @Prolog: Based on the link, I understand that there can be only single policy, that resolves Identity, which is Basic in my case. However, how do I add requirement for X-API-Key alongside the basic auth? I hope I can avoid writing custom middleware