# .Net Core Custom Authentication Scheme

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, .net-core, jwt

```
builder.AddJwtBearer(options =>
                {
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateIssuer = true,
                        ValidateAudience = true,
                        ValidIssuer = authOptions.Issuer,
                        ValidAudience = authOptions.Audience,
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(authOptions.Key)),
                    };
                })
                .AddScheme<AuthServerAuthenticationSchemeOptions, AuthServerAuthenticationHandler>("CustomAuth", options => { options.Authority = authOptions.Authority; });
        }
```

As from above code multiple authentications are added, what I want to achieve is if AddJwtBearer succeeds then request should forwarded to **CustomAuth**.
As per above code the **CustomAuth** does not get hit on **HandleAuthenticateAsync**, only JwtBearer is validating the request.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45695382/how-do-i-setup-multiple-auth-schemes-in-asp-net-core-2-0
hope this helps!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.